# Fit in with/fit along together

Tags: word-usage

If two words seem to be suitable together and sound amazing, as in a poetry, will it be natural to use:

> These two words fit in with each other.
>
> These two words fit in together.

Do these two sentences above sound natural?

I also came up with this one, though I think this one doesn't sound natural.

> These two words fit along together. 
>   (I don't think this sounds natural,  this rather makes it sound awkward)

Answer (score 1):

"Fit in" is a common phrasal verb, but it means something different from "fit together".  Literally, something "fits in" when it connects properly, or matches well with other objects.  For example, each of the blocks in this children's toy *fits in* with the hole made for it:

[image]

Figuratively, something or someone "fits in" when they *conform* to their environment or surroundings.  A new student at a school might "fit in" with the other students by dressing similarly, making friends, and/or adopting the same dialect.

The key similarity is that some object is neatly inserted into (or integrated with) another object.  You can't do this with two words -- or at least, you'd have to explain what you mean.  It's not obvious how one word fits in to another word.

Instead the natural idiom would be to say that two words **fit**, or **fit together**, because each fits with the other.  It's a balanced relationship.  For example, "peanut butter" is a substance with the consistency of *butter*, but made from *peanuts*.  It's a compound noun that makes sense.

Comment: Hi Andrew, can you please reply to: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/221363/get-out-in-a-game. Will "I **got out** two hours ago" sound better to you or "I **went out** two hours ago." Does "get out" sound better or "go out"? (I wanted different opinions because there are a lot of variations among answers by various native.....)

Answer (score 0):

I would be much more likely to say

> - These two words fit with each other.
> - These two words fit together.
> - These two words fit well together.
> - These two words go well together.
> - These two words work well together.

I can't say that "fit in" is wrong, but I have not heard it in this sort of usage very often.